# Which of the following equalities follows from $x>-2$?

Tags: calculus

For all $x>-2$, it follows that

a) $|x+2|=x-2$

b) $|x+2|=|x+1|+1$

c) $|x+2|=|x+1|-1$

d) None of the above follows from $x>-2.$

From the definition of the absolute values we have that

$$|x-a|=\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    x-a &  &, x\geq a  \\
    -(x-a)& &, x<a \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

So by rewriting $|x+2|=|x-(-2)|$ we see that $|x+2|=x+2$ for $x\geq-2$, thus it should be the same for $x>-2$. According to the book the correct answer is d). Why?

Comment: @anderstood It should be $x=-3/2$ for b.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. I turned my (extraodinary) comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to eliminate the three first cases with counterexamples. Take $x=0$ for a), $x=−3/2$ for b), $x=0$ for c) and you'll see that the only possibility is d). Note that $|x+2|=x+2$ is not in the list, otherwise that would be the correct choice.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to verify that $$|x+2|\gt x-2\space\space\text{for }x\in\mathbb R$$

$$ |x+2|\lt\ |x+1|+1 \space\text{for } -2\lt x\lt -1$$
$$|x+2|\gt |x+1|-1\space\space\text{for } x\gt-2$$ Consequently the correct answer is d).

Comment: The second inequality should read $|x + 2| < |x + 1| + 1$ for $-2 < x < -1$.  Observe that $$\left|-\frac{3}{2} + 1\right| = \left|-\frac{1}{2}\right| = \frac{1}{2} < \frac{3}{2} = \frac{1}{2} + 1 = \left|-\frac{1}{2}\right| + 1 = \left|-\frac{3}{2} + 1\right| + 1$$

Comment: Obviously, It was a typo error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: for $x>-2$ we have
a) $$x+2=x-2$$
b) $$x+2=x+1+1$$
c) $$x+2=x+1-1$$
nothhing follows from $x>-2$

Comment: Why the minus signs in the LHS?

Comment: sorry i thought it was $x<-2$ just corrected

Comment: What about b) (and c)), in the RHS? :D

Comment: for $|x+1|$ it can be $x>-1$ or $$x\le -1$$

Comment: For $-2<x\le-1$ we have $|x+1|=-x-1$.